# How to change width of default Scroll size in android?

Tags: android, scrollbar, scrollview

I have made a simple activity in android,in that i want to chande the width of scrollbar..My code for scroll View as below:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrProGhp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ivProGraph"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarSize="50dp"
        android:fillViewport="true" 
         android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
```

pls help me for it

Comment: To enable scrollbar, you have to put some views inside it first.

Comment: i have defined in default scroll bar...!

Comment: Have you tried with the Scrollbar property `android:scrollbarSize="100dip"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try **android:scrollbarSize="5dip"**

```
              <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mFriendsListView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:scrollbarSize="5dip"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/orange"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollingCache="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick is setting transparent(or opaque) stroke for your scrollbar drawables, in case you want your scrollbar smaller(or bigger)

Comment: and i'm talking about the bug of android 2.3 ignored scrollbar size